# Creating TimeEntry through REST API is taking too long

Tags: acumatica

The client is pushing Time Entries through Web Service Endpoints. Client is using PHP. I have created the .Net project for only Create Time Entry, but it never came back when Push, and HTTPClient is throwing exception "The task has been cancelled.".

Here is the PHP code for creating timeentry-

```html
<?php

require('config.php');
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client as Guzzle;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$cookies = new CookieJar();
define('AUTH', [
    'name' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD,
    'company' => COMPANY,
    'branch' => BRANCH
]);

login($cookies);

$timeEntry = makeTimeEntryArray();
// $acumaticaNoteID = sendTimeEntryToAcumatica($timeEntry, $cookies);

// $timeEntry['NoteID'] = ['value' => $acumaticaNoteID];
$timeEntry['NoteID'] = ['value' => 'e5eefc3b-7750-e711-8130-129da5b884cd'];
$timeEntry['BillableTime']['value'] = '0300';
$timeEntry['TimeSpent']['value'] = '0300';

$entityId = setTimeEntryStatusToOpen($timeEntry, $cookies);
$timeEntry['id'] = $entityId;

updateTimeEntryInAcumatica($timeEntry, $cookies);

$entityId = setTimeEntryStatusToOpen($timeEntry, $cookies);
$timeEntry['id'] = $entityId;

deleteTimeEntryInAcumatica($timeEntry, $cookies);

logout($cookies);

echo "Finished Create, Update, and Delete\n";

function makeTimeEntryArray()
{
    return [
        'NoteID' => ['value' => null],
        'Note' => ['value' => 'created by me'],
        'Billable' => ['value' => true],
        'BillableOvertime' => ['value' => '0000'],
        'BillableTime' => ['value' => '0200'],
        'Date' => ['value' => '2017-06-13T08:30:00-05:00'],
        'EarningType' => ['value' => 'RG'],
        'Overtime' => ['value' => '0000'],
        'Owner' => ['value' => EMPLOYEE_ID],
        'RelatedEntityDescription' => ['value' => ORDER_TYPE . ', ' . ORDER_NUMBER],
        'Status' => ['value' => 'Completed'],
        'Summary' => ['value' => 'Test Time Entry From PHP Sample Code'],
        'TimeSpent' => ['value' => '0200'],
        'TrackTime' => ['value' => true],
        'Type' => ['value' => 'TE'],
        'TypeDescription' => ['value' => 'Time Entry'],
        'RefNoteID' => ['value' => ORDER_NOTE_ID],
    ];
}

function login($cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Logging in, estimated 1s...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $resource = '<URL>/auth/login';

    echo "  url: $resource\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('POST', $resource, [
        'json' => AUTH,
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'http_errors' => false
    ]);

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        echo "Success logging in after {$elapsed}s\n";
        return;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} logging in after {$elapsed}s");
    }
}

function sendTimeEntryToAcumatica($data, $cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Attempting to create, estimated 300s...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $resource = '<URL>/6.00.001/TimeEntry';
    $dataJson = json_encode($data);

    echo "  url: $resource\n";
    echo "  data: " . json_encode($data) . "\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('PUT', $resource, [
        'json' => $data,
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        echo "Success creating time entry after {$elapsed}s\n";
        $responseJson = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        $acumaticaNoteID = $responseJson['NoteID']['value'];
        return $acumaticaNoteID;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} creating time entry after {$elapsed}s: {$response->getBody()}");
    }
}

function setTimeEntryStatusToOpen($data, $cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Opening time entry...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $updateParams = [
        'NoteID' => ['value' => $data['NoteID']['value']],
        'Status' => ['value' => 'Open'],
    ];

    $resource = '<URL>/6.00.001/TimeEntry';

    echo "  url: $resource\n";
    echo "  data: " . json_encode($updateParams) . "\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('PUT', $resource, [
        'json' => $updateParams,
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

    $responseBody = $response->getBody();
    $responseData = json_decode($responseBody);

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $responseData)) {
            echo "Success opening time entry after {$elapsed}s\n";
            return $responseData->id;
        } else {
            echo "Expected Acumatica to return an id for the time entry. Response: {$responseBody}\n";
            throw new Exception("Expected Acumatica to return an id");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} opening time entry after {$elapsed}s. Response: {$responseBody}");
    }
}

function updateTimeEntryInAcumatica($data, $cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Updating time entry...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $resource = '<URL>/6.00.001/TimeEntry';

    echo "  url: $resource\n";
    echo "  data: " . json_encode($data) . "\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('PUT', $resource, [
        'json' => $data,
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

    $responseBody = $response->getBody();

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        echo "Success updating time entry after {$elapsed}s\n";
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} updating time entry after {$elapsed}s. Response: {$responseBody}");
    }
}

function deleteTimeEntryInAcumatica($data, $cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Deleting time entry...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $resource = "<URL>/6.00.001/TimeEntry/{$data['id']}";

    echo "  url: $resource\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('DELETE', $resource, [
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $json = json_encode($response);
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        echo "Success deleting time entry after {$elapsed}s\n";
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} deleting time entry after {$elapsed}s. Response: {$json}");
    }
}

function logout($cookies)
{
    echo "-----------------------------------\n";
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Logging out...\n";
    $start = microtime(true);

    $resource = '<URL>/auth/logout';

    echo "  url: $resource\n";

    $guzzle = new Guzzle();
    $response = $guzzle->request('POST', $resource, [
        'cookies' => $cookies,
        'http_errors' => false
    ]);

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $json = json_encode($response);
    if ($code == 200 || $code == 204) {
        echo "Success logging out after {$elapsed}s\n";
        return;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error {$code} logging out after {$elapsed}s. . Response: {$json}");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it is taking too long to process. In a nutshell, when time entries are created, updated, or deleted, we place jobs onto a queue that handles them one at a time.

Push 
- makes one POST to the REST API with a json payload of the Time Entry's attributes.
Delete 
- makes one DELETE request to the REST API with a json payload of just the timeEntry id.
Update 
- makes two requests, one PUT to with a json payload setting the time entry to open, and a second PUT with a payload of the time entry attributes to make the changes.

Pushes today take around 350 seconds 
Delete Jobs are around 500 seconds 
Update Jobs are around 550 seconds to open, 250 seconds to update

Those times are not around any of code - that's how long its waiting for a response after the call to the REST API.

Here is the log from client, including JSON payload for the Create:-

[2017-06-09 18:12:16] local.INFO: [PushTimeEntryToAcumatica] [0] Starting PushTimeEntryToAcumatica

[2017-06-09 18:12:16] local.INFO: Current job queue count: 1

[2017-06-09 18:12:16] local.INFO: [PushTimeEntryToAcumatica] [0.05] Handling timeEntry {id: 174, user: Paul Wray, order: SO300276}

[2017-06-09 18:12:16] local.INFO: login url: /entity/auth/login

[2017-06-09 18:12:17] local.INFO: Success 204 from Acumatica: test

[2017-06-09 18:12:17] local.INFO: create url: /6.00.001/TimeEntry data: {"NoteID":{"value":null},"Note":{"value":"created by me"},"Billable":{"value":true},"BillableOvertime":{"value":"0000"},"BillableTime":{"value":"0180"},"Date":{"value":"2017-06-09T08:00:00-05:00"},"EarningType":{"value":"RG"},"Overtime":{"value":"0000"},"Owner":{"value":"EMP0000096"},"RelatedEntityDescription":{"value":"SO, SO300276"},"Status":{"value":"Completed"},"Summary":{"value":"Ryder Truck Rental - Des Moines-NW 49th- Paul Wray- 3hrs"},"TimeSpent":{"value":"0180"},"TrackTime":{"value":true},"Type":{"value":"TE"},"TypeDescription":{"value":"Time Entry"},"RefNoteID":{"value":"9af5eb4f-3934-e711-812f-12e7ddd1194d"}}

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: Success 200 from Acumatica: {"NoteID":{"value":null},"Note":{"value":"created by me"},"Billable":{"value":true},"BillableOvertime":{"value":"0000"},"BillableTime":{"value":"0180"},"Date":{"value":"2017-06-09T08:00:00-05:00"},"EarningType":{"value":"RG"},"Overtime":{"value":"0000"},"Owner":{"value":"EMP0000096"},"RelatedEntityDescription":{"value":"SO, SO300276"},"Status":{"value":"Completed"},"Summary":{"value":"Ryder Truck Rental - Des Moines-NW 49th- Paul Wray- 3hrs"},"TimeSpent":{"value":"0180"},"TrackTime":{"value":true},"Type":{"value":"TE"},"TypeDescription":{"value":"Time Entry"},"RefNoteID":{"value":"9af5eb4f-3934-e711-812f-12e7ddd1194d"}}

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: [UpdateTimeEntryInAcumatica] job dispatched for timeEntry id: 174

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: Current job queue count: 1

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: Success 204 from Acumatica: test

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: [PushTimeEntryToAcumatica] [193.89] SUCCESS handling timeEntry id:174

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: [PushTimeEntryToAcumatica] [193.89] SUCCESS handling id: 174

[2017-06-09 18:15:30] local.INFO: [PushTimeEntryToAcumatica] [193.89] Finished PushTimeEntryToAcumatica in 193.89 seconds

Acumatica Request Profiler

[image: Acumatica Request Profiler]

Part of WSDL for TimeEntry Endpoint

```html
<s:complexType name="TimeEntry">
 <s:complexContent mixed="false">
  <s:extension base="q4:Entity" xmlns:q4="http://www.acumatica.com/entity/Maestro/6.00.001/">
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="ActivityDetails" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Approver" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Billable" type="q4:BooleanValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="BillableOvertime" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="BillableTime" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Date" type="q4:DateTimeValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="EarningType" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Internal" type="q4:BooleanValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="NoteID" type="q4:GuidValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Overtime" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Owner" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Project" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="ProjectTask" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="ReferenceNbr" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="RefNoteID" type="q4:GuidValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="RelatedEntityDescription" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Released" type="q4:BooleanValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="StartTime" type="q4:DateTimeValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Status" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Summary" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Task" type="q4:GuidValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="TaskSummary" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="TimeSpent" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="TrackTime" type="q4:BooleanValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Type" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="TypeDescription" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    <s:element name="Workgroup" type="q4:StringValue" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:extension>
 </s:complexContent>
</s:complexType>
```

Endpoint Definition generated from utility-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Endpoint xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Maestro" version="6.00.001" systemContractVersion="2" xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/entity/maintenance/5.31">
  <ExtendsEndpoint name="Default" version="6.00.001" />
  <TopLevelEntity name="MaestroSalesOrder" screen="SO301000">
    <Fields>
      <Field name="AddressLine1" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="AddressLine2" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="City" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="CustomerName" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Date" type="DateTimeValue" />
      <Field name="DatePromised" type="DateTimeValue" />
      <Field name="Description" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Email" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Hold" type="BooleanValue" />
      <Field name="LicenseNumber" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Name" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Odometer" type="IntValue" />
      <Field name="OrderNbr" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="OrderType" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Phone1" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="PostalCode" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="State" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Status" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TankModel" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TankSpec" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TankVIN" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TankYearMake" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TAS" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TRS" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TruckModel" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TruckVIN" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TruckYearMake" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="UnitNumber" type="StringValue" />
    </Fields>
    <Mappings>
      <Mapping field="AddressLine1">
        <To object="Shipping_Address" field="AddressLine1" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="AddressLine2">
        <To object="Shipping_Address" field="AddressLine2" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="City">
        <To object="Shipping_Address" field="City" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="CustomerName">
        <To object="Document" field="CustomerID%AcctName" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Date">
        <To object="Document" field="OrderDate" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="DatePromised">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 11" field="UsrDatePromised" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Description">
        <To object="Document" field="OrderDesc" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Email">
        <To object="Shipping_Contact" field="Email" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Hold">
        <To object="Document" field="Hold" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="LicenseNumber">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 7" field="UsrLicenseNbr" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Name">
        <To object="Document" field="SalesPersonID%Descr" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Odometer">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 7" field="UsrOdometer" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="OrderNbr">
        <To object="Document" field="OrderNbr" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="OrderType">
        <To object="Document" field="OrderType" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Phone1">
        <To object="Shipping_Contact" field="Phone1" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="PostalCode">
        <To object="Shipping_Address" field="PostalCode" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="State">
        <To object="Shipping_Address" field="State%StateID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Status">
        <To object="Document" field="Status" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TankModel">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 9" field="UsrTankModel" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TankSpec">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 9" field="UsrTankSpec" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TankVIN">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 9" field="UsrTankVINInfo" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TankYearMake">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 9" field="UsrTankYearMake" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TAS">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 9" field="UsrTankTAS" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TRS">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 10" field="UsrTruckTRS" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TruckModel">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 10" field="UsrTruckModel" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TruckVIN">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 10" field="UsrTruckVINInfo" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TruckYearMake">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 10" field="UsrTruckYearMake" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="UnitNumber">
        <To object="CurrentDocument: 7" field="UsrUnitNbr" />
      </Mapping>
    </Mappings>
  </TopLevelEntity>
  <TopLevelEntity name="TimeEntry" screen="CR306010">
    <Fields>
      <Field name="ActivityDetails" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Approver" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Billable" type="BooleanValue" />
      <Field name="BillableOvertime" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="BillableTime" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Date" type="DateTimeValue" />
      <Field name="EarningType" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Internal" type="BooleanValue" />
      <Field name="NoteID" type="GuidValue" />
      <Field name="Overtime" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Owner" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Project" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="ProjectTask" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="ReferenceNbr" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="RefNoteID" type="GuidValue" />
      <Field name="RelatedEntityDescription" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Released" type="BooleanValue" />
      <Field name="StartTime" type="DateTimeValue" />
      <Field name="Status" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Summary" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Task" type="GuidValue" />
      <Field name="TaskSummary" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TimeSpent" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TrackTime" type="BooleanValue" />
      <Field name="Type" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="TypeDescription" type="StringValue" />
      <Field name="Workgroup" type="StringValue" />
    </Fields>
    <Mappings>
      <Mapping field="ActivityDetails">
        <To object="CurrentActivity" field="Body" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Approver">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="ApproverID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Billable">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="IsBillable" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="BillableOvertime">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="OvertimeBillable" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="BillableTime">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="TimeBillable" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Date">
        <To object="Activities" field="StartDate_Date" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="EarningType">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="EarningTypeID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Internal">
        <To object="Activities" field="IsPrivate" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="NoteID">
        <To object="Activities" field="NoteID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Overtime">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="OvertimeSpent" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Owner">
        <To object="Activities" field="OwnerID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Project">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="ProjectID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="ProjectTask">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="ProjectTaskID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="ReferenceNbr">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="ARRefNbr" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="RefNoteID">
        <To object="Activities" field="RefNoteID" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="RelatedEntityDescription">
        <To object="Activities" field="Source" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Released">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="Released" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="StartTime">
        <To object="Activities" field="ParentNoteID%StartDate" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Status">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="ApprovalStatus" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Summary">
        <To object="Activities" field="Subject" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Task">
        <To object="Activities" field="Subject" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TaskSummary">
        <To object="Activities" field="ParentNoteID!Subject" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TimeSpent">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="TimeSpent" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TrackTime">
        <To object="TimeActivity" field="TrackTime" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Type">
        <To object="Activities" field="Type" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="TypeDescription">
        <To object="Activities" field="Type_description" />
      </Mapping>
      <Mapping field="Workgroup">
        <To object="Activities" field="WorkgroupID" />
      </Mapping>
    </Mappings>
  </TopLevelEntity>
</Endpoint>
```

JSON Object

```html
{
 "NoteID": {
  "value": null
 },
 "Note": {
  "value": "Created by Krunal"
 },
 "Billable": {
  "value": true
 },
 "BillableOvertime": {
  "value": "0000"
 },
 "BillableTime": {
  "value": "0200"
 },
 "Date": {
  "value": "2017-06-27T08:00:00-05:00"
 },
 "EarningType": {
  "value": "RG"
 },
 "Overtime": {
  "value": "0000"
 },
 "Owner": {
  "value": "EMP0000002"
 },
 "RelatedEntityDescription": {
  "value": "SO, SO300279"
 },
 "Status": {
  "value": "Completed"
 },
 "Summary": {
  "value": "Test Please Ignore"
 },
 "TimeSpent": {
  "value": "0200"
 },
 "TrackTime": {
  "value": true
 },
 "Type": {
  "value": "TE"
 },
 "TypeDescription": {
  "value": "Time Entry"
 },
 "RefNoteID": {
  "value": "052F4A9B-8635-E711-812F-12E7DDD1194D"
 }
}
```

Response time for above request
[image]

After removing StartTime and TaskSummary
[image]

Comment: Have you tried profiling Acumatica's side?

Comment: Included Request Profiler in main question.

Comment: Can you also provide your endpoint definition? As far as I know, `TimeEntry` isn't a part of Default endpoint (the URI in request profiler supports that).

Comment: Included in TimeEntry Endpoint definition in main question

Comment: This is not an endpoint definition, this is a part of WSDL. You can get endpoint definition by exporting it via maintenance service (see [this utility](https://github.com/Acumatica/cb-cli), for example).

Comment: Added an error (in main question) while generating endpoint definition using the utility. I have created Maintenance531New as per my acumatica instance url. Also update few property in the code as required, as you can see. But still not able to generate definition. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: You're missing the fact that this is, in fact, a working command-line utility: `cb-cli.exe getSchema <your Acumatica instance url> -u <your admin username> -p <your admin password> Maestro 6.00.001`

Comment: Generated the endpoint definition and added to the main question. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Which version of Acumatica are you using?

Comment: Acumatica version 6.10.0472

Comment: Added JSON object and Postman screenshot for the response time it took.

Comment: I've filed a bug for this, we'll take a look into it.

Comment: Can you try removing `StartTime` and `TaskSummary` from mapped fields and see whether the behavior changes?

Comment: It is much lesser after removing StartTime and TaskSummary from mapped fields. Attached postman screenshot, tested after removing these two fields.

Comment: This one should be fixed in 6.1 Update 9.